# CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException with cursor.getInt()

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

this is my code:

```
 Log.d("MYTAG", "random number -->" + randomNumber);
 idRandomCards[i] = cursorTypeZero.getInt(randomNumber);
```

this is the error Log:

```
7620-7620/package D/MYTAG﹕ random number -->94
04-02 16:06:51.804    7620-7620/package D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
04-02 16:06:51.804    7620-7620/package W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting    with uncaught exception (group=0x41bafda0)
04-02 16:06:51.854    7620-7620/package D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1283K,     45% free 9237K/16608K, paused 42ms, total 46ms
04-02 16:06:51.864    7620-7620/package E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: package, PID: 7620
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 206
        at ecc
```

as you will see, the  random number in this case has the value of 94. the cursor.getCount() = 206.

why i have this exception?

i dont' wanna use the cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow() method, because i need a random row.

someone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the column does not exits. If I understood correctly. you want to move the cursor to the random position, and read the data from that row:

use

```
 cursor.moveToPosition(randomNumber);
```

and then read from the correct column, using `getColumnIndexOrThrow` to read the column's index. You should also check that randomNumber is between `0` and `cursor.getCount() - 1`

Answer (score 1):

trying using

```
 cursorTypeZero.moveToPosition(position)
```

before the getInt() method.
edit after @blackbelt answer..